# File sharing from OSX 10.6.8 to OS 9.2.2

Tags: snow-leopard, file-sharing, classic-mac-os

For several years I have updated my server on OS 9.2.2 using file sharing from OSX 10.5.8. Today I tried to update a file from another Mac with OSX 10.6.8. It mounts the OS 9 volume as usual and I can copy files from it but I can only write files with a total size of up to 5,006 bytes.

Does anybody have any thoughts about the likely cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

I now have Leopard and various versions of Snow Leopard installed on my Mac Pro and I get the following results:

All versions can mount a remote OS 9 volume or folder. Leopard can write files to the mounted volume without any difficulty. Some versions of Snow Leopard can write some files at a first attempt but some of these appear empty or corrupted.

I eventually found I could get consistent satisfactory results by using a bash script to write about 40kB to a dummy file twice. After this further files can be written without any difficulty until the connection is terminated. Whist this is slightly tedious I can live it.

Further insights or fixes would be of interest to me.

Here is my bash script:

```
open 'afp://user-name:password@###.###.###.###/volume/web-pages'; sleep 1; f(){ echo {a..z}{A..Z}{z..n} > /Volumes/volume/web-pages/dummy-file; }; f; f
```

Comment: Neville, it's not clear what you're trying to say here. I assume you're trying to add a comment to your question? If so, please add a comment instead. If you're trying to say you want the edit removed from your question for some reason, then you can rollback the edit by clicking on the 'edited' link above the user who edited your question so you can review the edits and then change or rollback the edit. If you mean something else altogether, please use the flag option below your question to seek help. Hope this all makes sense. :)

Comment: Thanks for the flag. I've now undeleted the answer as I see you've edited it a few times so I'm assuming this is how you now want it. If not, please let me know.

Comment: That is fine - thanks for your help - I got confused with multiple rollbacks - perhaps rollbacks are not a satisfactory way to remove passwords etc from history - - I cannot find a log out button, where is it?